# What is bash source path precedence?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there any proper documentation about where BASH `source` will find the script?

In my following testing, directory listed in the `PATH` variable has a higher precedence than the invoking directory.

I setup one `main.sh` file, and three `script.sh` files in different locations.

**/root/dir/main.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
source script.sh
```

**/root/dir/script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
printf 'same dir as script.sh\n'
```

**/root/script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
printf 'same dir of invoke\n'
```

**/root/bin/script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
printf 'in PATH dir\n'
```

And my `$PATH` environment variable contains `/root/bin`.

Invoke `main.sh` from `/root`. The `script.sh` in `/root/bin` takes the precedence.

```
# pwd
/root
# dir/main.sh 
in PATH dir
```

Just a control experiment. If `/root/bin/script.sh` is not available, `source script.sh` resolves to the invoke directory.

```
# mv -vi /root/bin/script.sh{,.bak}
renamed '/root/bin/script.sh' -> '/root/bin/script.sh.bak'
# pwd
/root
# dir/main.sh 
same dir of invoke
```

If `/root/script.sh` is also not available, `source script.sh` cannot find the file.

```
# mv -vi /root/script.sh{,.bak}
renamed '/root/script.sh' -> '/root/script.sh.bak'
# pwd
/root
# dir/main.sh 
dir/main.sh: line 2: script.sh: No such file or directory
# ls dir
main.sh  script.sh
```

I cannot find documentation about the `source` path precedence. In the following webpage, it says *current directory is having a higher precedence that the PATH directory*. This contradicts my findings.

https://opensource.com/article/20/6/bash-source-command#search-for-source

> When you use source in Bash, it searches your current directory for the file you reference. This doesn't happen in all shells, so check
> your documentation if you're not using Bash.
>
> If Bash can't find the file to execute, it searches your PATH instead.
> Again, this isn't the default for all shells, so check your
> documentation if you're not using Bash.

Comment: See `LESS='+/^SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS' man bash`

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins

Comment: Thanks. In both docs, PATH has a higher precedence than the current directory.

Comment: The document you read (https://opensource.com/article/20/6/bash-source-command#search-for-source) is wrong. If filename argument of `source` doesn't contain a `/`: Bash first searches the directories in `$PATH`. If the file isn't found there _and_ Bash is not in POSIX mode then it searches the current directory.

Comment: Thanks both of you. As a side note, if the source path contains a `/`, it always resolves to the current directory. For example `source lib/script.sh` cannot resolve to `/root/bin/lib/script.sh`. This is the behaviour of $PATH, mentioned in [another SE thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17715/150246). This makes me harder to organize my scripts and libraries inside `/root/bin` and `/root/bin/lib`. I can add both directories to $PATH, but `source blah` is less self-descriptive than `source lib/blah`.

Comment: Moreover, I cannot have two libraries with the same name inside different directories. The files in the higher precedence directory in $PATH (i.e. the preceding directory in the $PATH list) is always called. The other libraries of the same name in the lower precedence directories can never be referenced.

Comment: And though enough people seem to think this has to do with programming I hold that this is a question for [unix.se] ...